# Kinect for Windows - No Device connected

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey :),

i got some issues using a Kinect for Windows.

I find out that this Kinect is not supported by Openni yet. [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/30889/cannot-launch-openni_camera-no-devices-connected-ros-electric/) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/openni-dev/ZI2ZmCRDwnA) and this command:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

throws an error like this:

```
[/openni_node1] No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

I tryed to use the unstable version of openni and ps-engine as mentioned at [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise-1204/) question but this sill not works.
So the real Question whitch arives. Is there some kind of workaround for this issue?

for advising purposes: **The *easy* solution for this issue was just to take an older Version of Kinect.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48210/kinect-for-windows---no-device-connected/) by [paetti88](https://answers.ros.org/users/3469/paetti88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Kinect4Windows can be made to work. The links below must help.

link for kinect 4 windows on ubuntu.........or mitchtech

http://www.20papercups.net/programming/kinect-on-ubuntu-with-openni/

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/openni-dev/h0F6kYCNigs/BR6iqqFhSJ8J

http://mitchtech.net/ubuntu-kinect-openni-primesense/

If openni does not build then, install openjdk-7-jre and openjdk-7-jdk

after cd SensorKinect
type git checkout unstable

openni_camera and openni_launch wont wont in the first go and say that this file "XnCppWrapper.h" is missing. Search for it and move all the contents of that folder to the /usr/include/

Never do rosdep for openni_Camera or openni_launch beacuase the unstable openni packages will be replaced by the stable ones..

Finally you can you roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch to get the new Kinect4Windows to work

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0